# actualizar campos en un dataframe desde otro comparando columnas

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Estoy intentando actualizar varios campos de un dataframe con valores de otro dataframe donde coindida un valor de otra columna
pongo ejemplo
Este seria el Dataframe a actualizar

```
df_a = 
  valor1    valor2     valor3    id_valor1    id_valor2    id_valor3
  V_1_C      V_2_B      v_3_A        na          na             na
  V_1_A      V_2_B      v_3_A        na          na             na        
  V_1_A      V_2_C                   na          na             na        
  V_1_B      V_2_D      v_3_A        na          na             na        
  V_1_B                              na          na             na        
  V_1_B      V_2_B      v_3_B        na          na             na
```

Este el de los datos con los id's

```
df_b = 
  id       val
  V_1_A     0
  V_1_B     1
  V_1_C     2
  V_2_B     3
  V_2_C     4
  V_2_D     5
  V_3_A     6
  V_3_B     7
```

Y me este seria el resultado esperado

```
df_a = 
  valor1    valor2     valor3    id_valor1    id_valor2    id_valor3
  V_1_C      V_2_B      v_3_A        2           3              6
  V_1_A      V_2_B                   0           3              na        
  V_1_A      V_2_C                   0           4              na        
  V_1_B      V_2_D      v_3_A        1           5              6     
  V_1_B                              1           na             na        
  V_1_B      V_2_B      v_3_B        1           3              7
```

Lo intento hacer con un merge, dentro de un for para hacerlo columna a columna

```
#cat list es la lista de valores (valor1 valor2 valor3)
for cat in cats_list:  
    nombre='id_' + cat 
    df1[nombre] = pd.merge(left=df1,right=df2, how='left', left_on=cat, right_on='id')[['val']]
```

esto funciona bien la primera iteracion, pero la segunda mete valores donde no corresponde.

Como si funciona es con un iterrows, pero tarda mucho.
¿Alguna idea ?

Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 5):

No hace falta complicar todo usando un `merge`, podemos llevar esto a lo más simple. ¿Cómo lo haríamos para una sola columna?, para esto podemos ayudarnos de un *filtro* típico de pandas.

```py
df[df["col"] == "valor"]
```

Esto nos dará todos los resultados que, en el `df` la columna `col` sea igual a `"valor"`, esto es básicamente lo que necesitas, perooo.... necesitamos hacerlo para cada uno de los valores de cada una de las columnas. Para estas *iteraciones* existe el método `apply()` de los *DataFrames*, este método permite pasarle una función para realizar una acción más amplia. Sintaxis:

```py
df.apply(func)
```

Mayormente se le pasa una función anónima o *lambda function* (función lambda), cuya sintaxis es:

```py
lambda parámetros: operación
```

En el caso de `apply()` el parámetro que se le pasa a la función es el valor de una columna (o fila). Armando la función quedaría algo así:

```py
df["valor1"].apply(lambda x: df_b[df_b["id"] == x])
```

Aquí escogemos la columna `valor1` de nuestro *DataFrame* (que sería el `df_a` en tu caso) y utilizamos el método `apply()` donde le pasamos una función, la operación que se realizará en este caso será un filtro, donde obtendremos todos los valores del `df_b` que sean iguales al valor obtenido (variable `x`), esto nos dará un resultado algo así:

```py
    id  val
2   V_1_C   2
```

Pero nosotros solo queremos el valor ubicado en la columna `val`, por lo que tendremos que hacer `df["valor1"].apply(lambda x: df_b[df_b["id"] == x]["val"])`. Si imprimimos eso,  obtenemos:

```
0   1   2
0   NaN NaN 2.0
1   0.0 NaN NaN
2   0.0 NaN NaN
3   NaN 1.0 NaN
4   NaN 1.0 NaN
5   NaN 1.0 NaN
```

Esto se debe a que el resultado del filtro aplicado es una Serie y no es un valor numérico en si, para ello utilizamos el método `item()` el cual nos permite obtener el *valor*, quedando `df["valor1"].apply(lambda x: df_b[df_b["id"] == x]["val"].item())`. Con eso ya obtendríamos lo que esperamos:

```
0    2
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
```

Esto es prácticamente todo lo que necesitamos, excepto que hay veces en los que los valores de `valorx` está vacío, por ejemplo en la columna `valor2` y `valor3`. Para estos casos simplemente hace falta un `if` en la función `lambda`, pero dado que todo se trabaja en una sola línea utilizaremos la sintaxis de un operador ternario.

```py
<valor_verdader> if <condicón> else <valor_falso>
```

Para la condición estableceremos si el valor está en el `df_b`, si está obtenemos el valor (con la expresión de antes) y si no está, le pondremos un valor por defecto, por ejemplo `"NaN"`. Para saber si el valor existe utilizaremos el método `isin()` donde le pasaremos una lista con los valores a verificar (una lista de un valor), pero dado que habrá un problema de *ambigüedad* para pandas tendremos que usar el método `any()` lo que nos devuelve `True` si alguno de los valores es `True`, de lo contrario `False`, quedando así:

```py
<valor_verdadero> if df_b["id"].isin([x]).any() else "NaN"
```

La expresión completa quedaría así:

```py
df["valor1"].apply(lambda x: df_b[df_b["id"] == x]["val"].item() if df_b["id"].isin([x]).any() else "NaN")
```

Teniendo este valor solo tenemos que guardarlo en la columna que deseamos.

```py
df["id_valor1"] = df["valor1"].apply(lambda x: df_b[df_b["id"] == x]["val"].item() if df_b["id"].isin([x]).any() else "NaN")

#lo mismo para los otros valores
df["id_valor2"] = df["valor2"].apply(lambda x: df_b[df_b["id"] == x]["val"].item() if df_b["id"].isin([x]).any() else "NaN")
df["id_valor3"] = df["valor3"].apply(lambda x: df_b[df_b["id"] == x]["val"].item() if df_b["id"].isin([x]).any() else "NaN")
```

Sin embargo vemos que hay mucho código repetido y podemos simplificarlo con un simple `for` dado que el nombre de las columnas solo varía el número.

```py
for i in range(1,4): #empieza en 1 y termina en 3
    df[f"id_valor{i}"] = df[f"valor{i}"].apply(lambda x: df_b[df_b["id"] == x]["val"].item() if df_b["id"].isin([x]).any() else "NaN")
```

Si volvemos a imprimir el *DataFrame* obtendremos esto:

|  | valor1 | valor2 | valor3 | id_valor1 | id_valor2 | id_valor3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | V_1_C | V_2_B | v_3_A | 2 | 3 | NaN |
| 1 | V_1_A | V_2_B | v_3_A | 0 | 3 | NaN |
| 2 | V_1_A | V_2_C | na | 0 | 4 | NaN |
| 3 | V_1_B | V_2_D | v_3_A | 1 | 5 | NaN |
| 4 | V_1_B |  |  | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 5 | V_1_B | V_2_B | v_3_B | 1 | 3 | NaN |

En la columna `id_valor3` salen todos `NaN` por que te haz equivocado en el nombre y has puesto las primeras letras en minúsculas y no en mayúsculas, esto me lleva a aclarar que los valores que quieras comprobar del `df_a` deben estar igual que en el `df_b`, así que ten cuidado :D.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo.
El problema es que hay ids repetidos en el df_b con distinto val.
Esto correspon de a un catalogo y el df_b son las categorias y estan anidadas como padre-hijo, y en este modelo de datos que han implementado hay casos con 1 hijo para varios padres
Quedaria tal que así
y asi a la hora de comparar el V_2_D tendria dos ids distintos,y por eso falla.

```
df_b = 
  id       val  padre
  V_1_A     0    na
  V_1_B     1    0
  V_1_C     2    0
  V_2_B     3    na
  V_2_C     4    3
  V_2_D     5    4
  V_2_D     6    3
  V_3_A     7    na
  V_3_B     8    7
```

Lo que es unico es la tupla con padre hijo.
Una estructura un poco sin sentido, pero esta montado asi

gracias

Comment: Si tienes algo que añadir hazlo en la pregunta.

Comment: EL error es efectivamente por lo que dices, sin embargo si tu dices que lo que es único es la tupla, entonces como quieres obtener el valor de acuerdo a solo el id?. Aparte el id debería de ser único